# Poetry: because of requirement unavailability need to downgrade python. How to best manage

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I am using poetry and had generated an environment with **python 3.11.1**, after which I needed to add the **stanza** package which needs the **torch** package and it turns out that the latter does not exist yet for python 3.11.

I installed **python 3.10** (3.10.9) with **pyenv** and created a new poetry env with it and checked that stanza (and torch) install happily with a `poetry add stanza` command

If I change the python version in the original **pyproject.toml** from 3.11.1 to 3.10.9, how can I be sure that the other packages get the correct level?

Here are the dependencies in current my python 3.11.1 TOML file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "isagog-ai"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Isagog's AI packages"
authors = ["Robert Alexander <aaaaaaaaa@yyyyy.xxx>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "isagog_ai"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11.1"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.2.1"
pytest-cov = "^4.0.0"
pre-commit = "^3.0.1"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
mypy = "^0.991"
isort = "^5.11.4"
black = "^22.12.0"
pylint = "^2.15.10"
```

Comment: How many of your pinned requirements *need* Python 3.11? I would just start by trying to change the `python` requirement, and change the others as needed when and if installation fails. Or, unpin the versions and see what gets installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Very new to this and still wrapping my head around it :)